# Do I need to load all JSON fields to make it work on Android with retrofit lib?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm writing some Android app which pulls data in JSON format and I'm using retrofit library.

I've got one question, do I need to make POJO class which contains all fields that JSON object has? because in my case JSON objects from API have about 40 fields and I need only few of them.

I have done some test with sample app. There were JSONs containing 3 fields and when commented everything related to one single field app stopped loading and showing any results (no adapter attached error).

So I'm guessing that I have to make call for full JSON object and eventually not inflate all data into views?

Comment: Short answer: no you don't. Just make sure the fields you want in your POJO have the same name as the JSON or use @SerializedName("<the Json field name>") above them.

Comment: try pasting your code here